# Vkontakte API ошибка: error: invalid_client, error_description; client_id is incorrect

Tags: android, вконтакте

Делаю авторизацию в вк по [этому видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aS0S9Pk9yc).

Постоянно выскакивает

> {error: invalid_client, error_description; client_id is incorrect}

На устройстве имеется официальный вк клиент. Там я авторизирован. Пробовал удалить его - то же самое. 
Когда записал этот официальный клиент снова, там я уже не был авторизирован. При этом в моем приложении тоже выплыло окно авторизации. 
Когда же авторизировался в офиц клиенте, то в моем приложении появилась та же ошибка.

Comment: Вроде бы проблема крылась в том, что не инициализировал SDK в onCreate приложения.

Answer (score 9):

Всем, у кого возникает проблема `error invalid_client error_description client_id is incorrect`, необходимо добавить в манифест в тег `<Application>` строку `android:name=".ClassName "`, где `ClassName` – название класса, который вы унаследовали от `android.app.Application` и в одном из методов которого происходит вызов `VKSdk.initialize();`

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая проблема, потому что я не удалил двоеточия в sha1 ключе, когда регистрировал приложение в панели разработчика в vk.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая проблема была, потому, что я вместо VK Application ID, вписывал VK Secure Key, а вместо VK Secure Key — Сервисный ключ доступа. Простая невнимательность :)

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Понял, благодарю вас за полезную информацию.

Comment: Интересно, что русскоязычная версия сайта отслеживает репутацию отдельно от англоязычной версии.