# VK SDK Android ошибка авторизации

Tags: java, android, android-vksdk

Хочу авторизоваться в своем приложении через VK во фрагменте.

```
public class SignInFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btnSignIn;

    public static SignInFragment newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        SignInFragment fragment = new SignInFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in_fragment, container, false);

        btnSignIn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Доступ к друзьям
                String[] scope = new String[]{
                        VKScope.FRIENDS
                };
                VKSdk.login(getActivity(), scope);

            }
        });



        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {

            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Успешная авторизация", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onError(VKError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Что-то пошло не так.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class SignInActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, getPackageName());
//        Log.d("FINGERPRINTS", "onCreate: " + Arrays.asList(fingerprints));

    }

    @Override
    protected Fragment getFragment() {
        return SignInFragment.newInstance();
    }
}
```

App

```
public class App extends Application {

    VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) {
            if(newToken == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        vkAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        VKSdk.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

После авторизации появляется окно с json:

```
{"error": "invalid_client", "error_description":"client_id is incorrect"}
```

Почему так происходит? (у меня вместо Id находится текст, но оригинальный id же тоже виден)

**Update**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">VKMobileApp</string>
    <integer name="com_vk_sdk_AppId">6861226</integer>

    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
    <string name="button_vk_sign_in">Авторизоваться через VK</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: В ошибке сказано, что не тот `client_id` вы указали. Вы его указали в нужном месте нужным образом согласно документации?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб он не указывается вообще. Единственный id, который указывается, это app_id, но я его добавил в strings

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644082/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, помогло